# Send sp_send_dbmail only if results are available

Tags: sql, sql-server, email

I want to send an e-mail from my database only if the executed query has output and is not empty. 
I was wondering how I can do this and where to embed this into my code. On top of my head, I thought of counting the results and having count > 0 or maybe something with the query in conjunction with @@rowcount > 0. What would you suggest?
Here is my code:

```
ALTER proc dbo.spBornBefore2000 as
set nocount on 
DECLARE @sub VARCHAR(100),
 @qry VARCHAR(max),
 @msg VARCHAR(250),
 @query NVARCHAR(max),
 @tab char(1) = CHAR(9)

SELECT @sub = 'before 1990 -' + cast(getdate() as varchar(100)) 
SELECT @msg = N'blablabla.....'
SELECT @query = ' select id, name, dob, year(dob) as birth_year 
                     from people
                     where year(dob) < 2000  '

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
            @profile_name = 'USERS',
            @recipients =  'abc@gmail.com',
            @body = @msg,
            @subject = @sub,
            @query = @query,
            @query_attachment_filename = 'before2000.csv',
            @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
            @query_result_header = 1,
            @query_result_width = 256 ,
            @query_result_separator = @tab,
            @query_result_no_padding =1;
```

Comment: IF EXISTS(your query here)...

Comment: @SeanLange Please check my answer below. I tried to incorporate the advice you gave me and if the results are present the job will execute and send a file to person abc and if the results are not existent I will receive a message that there are no results. Is my code right? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

EXEC(@query)
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        -- send email here
    END

Answer (score 0):

```
  ALTER proc dbo.spBornBefore2000 as
    set nocount on 
    DECLARE @sub VARCHAR(100),
     @qry VARCHAR(max),
     @msg VARCHAR(250),
     @query NVARCHAR(max),
     @tab char(1) = CHAR(9)

    SELECT @sub = 'before 1990 -' + cast(getdate() as varchar(100)) 
    SELECT @msg = N'blablabla.....'
    SET @query = ' select id, name, dob, year(dob) as birth_year 
                         from people
                         where year(dob) < 2000  '

    IF EXISTS (select id, name, dob, year(dob) as birth_year 
                         from people
                         where year(dob) < 2000)
        begin

            EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                        @profile_name = 'USERS',
                        @recipients =  'abc@gmail.com',
                        @body = @msg,
                        @subject = @sub,
                        @query = @query,
                        @query_attachment_filename = 'before2000.csv',
                        @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
                        @query_result_header = 1,
                        @query_result_width = 256 ,
                        @query_result_separator = @tab,
                        @query_result_no_padding =1;
        end
    ELSE
        begin
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                        @profile_name = 'USERS',
                        @recipients =  'myself@gmail.com',
                        @body = 'No results returned'
        end
```

Comment: This is close. But you have to have a query for EXISTS, not just a string. You would either need to copy your string to the inside of the EXISTS or modify this a bit.